# Adding Touch States with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, mobile, touch

http://jsfiddle.net/JamesKyle/Ke536/

As you can see I did with the `hover` and `active` classes, I am trying to find a simple way of adding simple touch events to all elements on the page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// MOUSE
    $('*').mouseover(function() {$(this).addClass('hover');});
    $('*').mouseout(function() {$('.hover').removeClass('hover');});

    $('*').mousedown(function() {$(this).addClass('active');});
    $('*').mouseup(function() {$('.active').removeClass('active');});

// TOUCH
    // On touch down wait (100ms) > add class touch
    // On touch move > remove class touch

    // On touch up > add class active
});
```

I want there to be a slight delay before adding the touch class so that it doesn't trigger when the user is actually scrolling which is why I also want to remove the class on touch move.

> You can see the jsfiddle here:
>   http://jsfiddle.net/JamesKyle/Ke536/

Answer (score 0):

Look at the events `touchstart`, `touchmove` and `touchend`.

You can programmatically determine the time taken using a delta with `+new Date`.